# C Runtime Error?

Tags: c

I'm writing a program for self checkout system in C and everything seems to be working fine, but I am getting a Runtime error when I calculate the total when I include a scanf() to get the amount of items in the cart.

```
int initial;
int numOfItems;
double tax;
double total;


printf("How many items do you have?\n");

//If I remove this and place a number (priceOfItems[23], for example)
//then I don't get a Runtime error but I need the scanf to get the number of 
//items from the user
scanf("%d", &numOfItems);

//Pass the number in the cart to the array
double priceOfItems[23]; //this is an example with the fixed number

printf("How much is this item?\n");

//For loop to store the user input
for (initial = 0; initial < 22; initial++)
{
    printf("Item %d: ", initial);
    scanf("%lf", &priceOfItems[initial]);
}

//For loop for calculating the Tax and Total
for (initial = 0; initial < 22; initial++)
{
    total = total + priceOfItems[initial];
    tax = SALES_TAX * priceOfItems[initial];
}

printf("-------------------------\n");

printf("TOTAL: %.2lf\n", total);
printf("TAX: %.2lf\n", tax);
```

Comment: `I am getting a Runtime error` I love when the _actual error_ that literally explains the reason for the failure is omitted from the question.. Voting to close for lack of context.

Comment: Do you need to initialize numOfItems first?

Comment: What do you use in place of `double priceOfItems[23];` when you read `numOfItems`?

Comment: Post the code that gets the error, not the working code.

Comment: It was originally double priceOfItems[numOfItems] @LouFranco

Comment: That is the code that gets the error @Barmar

Comment: That's a compile time error

Comment: So you get an error when you have that `scanf`, even though you never use the variable in the rest of the code?

Comment: `%lf` doesn't make sense in `printf`. Either you're using C99+ (then it's the same as `%f`), or you're using C89/C90 (then it's undefined behavior).

Comment: Thanks @NeilStoker I just needed to initialize double total and int numOfItems and the error is gone.